# New to Phaser: Can't get the player's body.velocity.y to change when cursor.up.isDown. Is something blocking it?

Tags: phaser-framework

I am trying to learn how to build a simple platform game with Phaser, but I am having trouble getting the player to jump.

I can see that it is detecting when the "up" button is being pressed, but for some reason the player does not move. My jump code is identical to other examples I have seen, so I am assuming the problem is elsewhere in the file. Do I perhaps need to change the player's gravity or something? I was also wondering if it could be because the game thinks the player is colliding with a wall?

Here is a codepen:
https://codepen.io/moorehannah/pen/RXRroK

and this is the specific code for the jump:

```
if (this.cursor.up.isDown && this.player.body.onFloor) {
   this.player.body.velocity.y = -320;
   console.log("up");
}
```

The tutorial I followed is this one:
http://www.lessmilk.com/tutorial/2d-platformer-phaser

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The code is correct I don't see anything wrong, are you using Phaser 3 or Phaser 2 (CE) ? So we can dig more

Comment: Thank you for the codepen that I have forked to debug your code so I just have reversed the lines that handles the collision to make them before the cursor tests and it worked https://codepen.io/nazimboudeffa/pen/aepdrr it happens sometimes to make things in a certain order to see them working

Comment: Thank you so much nazimboudeffa! That is so strange, I would have never figured that out.

Comment: You're welcome, I guess it's fixed, so yes it's strange and I have learnt this by coding a lot of games so now I know that sometimes the order in which instructions are fiered matters

Answer (score 0):

The gravity may be too high. You could see if changing `onFloor` to `standing` works, or you could even use `this.player.body.blocked.down`